# primary key is null when printed, and result is retrieved but when printing it the ID is still null

Tags: flutter, sqflite

the user id is null, the column is primary key and it should not be possible to have it be null

I'm learning Flutter and SQFlite, I'm following the example in the course on Udemey, and I'm typing it to the letter, but it's working for the instructor and it's not working for me

I simplified everything, now it's one file, still, ID is null

main.dart

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

void main() async {
//  debugPrint("Hello World");
  var db = dbhelp();
  User user1 = User("User1");
  int insertResult = await db.saveUser(user1);
  debugPrint("insert result is " + insertResult.toString());
  User searchResult = await db.retrieveUser(insertResult);
  debugPrint(searchResult.toString());
}

class dbhelp {
  static final dbhelp _instance = dbhelp.internal();
  dbhelp.internal();
  factory dbhelp() => _instance;
  static Database _db;
  void _onCreate(Database _db, int newVersion) async {
    await _db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE MYTABLE(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, userName TEXT NOT NULL)");
  }

  Future<Database> initDB() async {
    Directory documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentDirectory.path, "appdb.db");
    Database newDB = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return newDB;
  }

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) {
      return _db;
    } else {
      _db = await initDB();
      return _db;
    }
  }

  Future<int> saveUser(User user) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    int result;
    var userMap = user.toMap();
    result = await dbClient.insert("MYTABLE", userMap);
    return result;
  }

  Future<User> retrieveUser(int id) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    if (id == null) {
      print("The ID is null, cannot find user with Id null");
      var nullResult =
          await dbClient.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID is null");
      return User.fromMap(nullResult.first);
    }
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID = $id";
    var result = await dbClient.rawQuery(sql);
    if (result.length != 0) {
      return User.fromMap(result.first);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

class User {
  String _userName;
  int _id;
  String get userName => _userName;
  int get id => _id;
  User(this._userName, [this._id]);
  User.map(dynamic obj) {
    this._userName = obj['userName'];
    this._id = obj['id'];
  }
  User.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    this._userName = map["userName"];
    if (map["id"] != null) {
      this._id = map["id"];
    } else {
      print("in fromMap, Id is null");
    }
  }
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    Map map = Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["userName"] = this._userName;
    if (_id != null) {
      map["id"] = _id;
    } else {
      print("in toMap, id is null");
    }
    return map;
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return "ID is ${this._id} , Username is ${this._userName} }";
  }
}
```

when i print the id it should print a number not null

but it is always null

Comment: Please also post your output

Answer (score 1):

I was puzzled for a while. A simple print after your select shows the issue:

```dart
String sql = "SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE ID = $id";
var result = await dbClient.rawQuery(sql);
print(result);
```

output:

```
[{ID: 1, userName: User1}]
```

Column names are case sensitive.You use sometimes `id`  (in toMap/fromMap) and sometimes `ID` (in your create table). Make sure to always use the same name everywhere.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean, your line does not appear in my code, and there is no line that has it as print result.

Comment: I added the line where I added the print. The core issue is that you should use `id` or `ID` but not both!